# Is there a window dbgview in Linux sytem?

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, syslog

DbgView is the tool for Windows debug. What is similar to Window debug view in Ubuntu/Linux? How to real time read debug message in Linux (same as dbgView in Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after, since I'm not familiar with DbgView, but it sounds like what you might be after is [dmesg.](http://www.linfo.org/dmesg.html) This displays the system log (including kernel debug statements).

If you can clarify is exactly the functionality you're after, you might get a better response. For example, when you say "real time read debug message," what is it you want to debug?